# Show Cost Data by Month based on Date Range

Tags: sql

I have an existing table (jobCost) that has cost data by type and month as shown in the example here.

| Job | Month | Material | Labor | Equip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/1/22 | 50.00 | 25.00 | 75.00 |
| 123 | 02/1/22 | 20.00 | 45.00 | 60.00 |
| 123 | 03/1/22 | 10.00 | 35.00 | 25.00 |

I have an existing table (jobDetails) that contains the job start and end date (for example start 12/15/2021 and end 5/15/2022).

I want to create a table that shows one row for each month in the date range and then provides the total cost for each month as shown here.

| Month | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| 12/21 | 0 |
| 01/22 | 150.00 |
| 02/22 | 125.00 |
| 03/22 | 70.00 |
| 04/22 | 0 |
| 05/22 | 0 |

I found the query below which will successfully convert my job start and end dates to rows, but I don't know how to have the datetime in the declare statement read from my existing data (as the dates are different for each job). If I can figure that out, then I can join the cost data to this by month.

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '12/15/2021'
       ,@EndDate   datetime = '5/15/2022'
;

WITH theDates AS
     (SELECT @StartDate as theDate
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, theDate)
        FROM theDates
       WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, theDate) <= @EndDate
     )
SELECT theDate as theValue
  FROM theDates
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Here is the Job details sample table and query.

| Job | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 12/3/2021 | 05/30/2022 |

```
SELECT
    Job
    ,StartDate
    ,EndDate
FROM 
    JobDetails
```

Here is the query for the job cost

```
SELECT 
    jc.Month
    ,CASE WHEN ct.Category = 'L' THEN SUM(jc.Cost) END as LaborCost
    ,CASE WHEN ct.Category = 'E' THEN SUM(jc.Cost) END as EquipmentCost
    ,CASE WHEN ct.Category = 'M' THEN SUM(jc.Cost) END as MaterialCost

FROM
    JobCost jc
    INNER JOIN CostCategory ct ON jc.Group = ct.Group AND jc.CostType = ct.CostType

GROUP BY
    jc.Month
```

Comment: Can you show what you HAVE attempted?  This really should be a basic query with simple aggregates sum(), group by month.  The bigger issue is you just have the date field with just a month/year which is not good for long-term trying to query.  They should be stored as actual date fields.

Comment: I've updated my table to reflect more accurately what the data is really stored like (1st of each month). I have no issue with the sum() and group functions. I've expanded my question to include the query I found for converting my dates to rows and where I'm stuck with it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this mySQL? Please post sample data from the jobDetails table and give the table definitions `SHOW CREATE TABLE jobDetails;`  & `SHOW CREATE TABLE jobCost;`

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I added the information you requested. If you're able to assist, it would be greatly appreciated. This is SQL, not mySQL.